# Get and display ajax response success data

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

How do I get and display data from an Ajax response?

This is what it returned to the console.

```
{current_page: 1, data: Array(15), …}
current_page: 1
data: Array(15)
0:
  amount: "1000.00"
  code: "00000020"
  content_id: 5
  content_type: "App\\Models\\Downpayment"
  created_at: "2021-10-06T01:43:41.000000Z"
  deleted_at: null
  description: "desc"
  items: [{…}]
  name: "Downpayment 1"
  owner_id: 2
  owner_type: "App\\Models\\Member"
  updated_at: "2021-10-06T01:43:41.000000Z"
  updated_by: null
  [[Prototype]]: Object
1: {id: 21, …
```

The returned data is in the array form. When the option is selected, its detailed data will be displayed inside the table.

This is my current script:

```
$( '#invoice' ).change(function() {
            console.log('invoice selected!')

            var optionSelected = $(this).find("option:selected");
            invoiceSelected  = optionSelected.val();
            console.log(invoiceSelected);

            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                cache: false,
                url : "{{ route('credit-notes.invoices') }}",
                data: { invoice : invoiceSelected },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log('success');
                    console.log(data);

                    invoice_id              = invoiceSelected
                    invoice_name            = data.name // get the data from success response
                    invoice_date            = data.created_at
                    invoice_description     = data.description
                    invoice_amount          = data.amount

                    var row = '<tr id="row-' + invoice_id + '" class="invoice-row">' +
                        '<td>' + '<input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;' + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + invoice_name + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + invoice_date + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + invoice_description + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + invoice_amount + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>';
                    $('#invoice-tbody').append(row);
                }
            });
        })
        .change();
```

Comment: try invoice_name            = data.data.name // get the data from success response

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Comment: You return JSON, you need to handle JSON. Look at `$.getJSON` function. Then, you return an array, you understand you must handle several elements so ?

Answer (score 0):

Above response seems to be an array response, so you need to add loop above the table row to append those values. I have added loop to the code below.  Check syntax if its not working.

```
   $( '#invoice' ).change(function() {
                console.log('invoice selected!')
    
                var optionSelected = $(this).find("option:selected");
                invoiceSelected  = optionSelected.val();
                console.log(invoiceSelected);
    
                $.ajax({
                    type: "get",
                    cache: false,
                    url : "{{ route('credit-notes.invoices') }}",
                    data: { invoice : invoiceSelected },
                    success: function(data) {
                      console.log('success');
                      console.log(data);
                      data.forEach(val,index){
                        invoice_id              = invoiceSelected
                        invoice_name            = val.name // get the data from success response
                        invoice_date            = val.created_at
                        invoice_description     = val.description
                        invoice_amount          = val.amount
    
                        var row = '<tr id="row-' + invoice_id + '" class="invoice-row">' +
                            '<td>' + '<input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;' + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + invoice_name + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + invoice_date + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + invoice_description + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + invoice_amount + '</td>' +
                        '</tr>';
                      }

                        $('#invoice-tbody').append(row);
                    }
                });
            })
            .change();
```

Comment: This display all data item, I need to display the selected option's data item only..

Comment: Instead of data.name use data[0].name. data[0]  is first element from an array.